# convert same format string to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

If I have a string like below:

```
[{"id":123, "name": "Sally", "age": 36}
{"id":138, "name": "Nicholas", "age": 48}
{"id":194, "name": "Steven", "age": 25}]
```

Is there a way for me to convert it to object? Since, their format is pretty much the same. Do correct me and let me know if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: This is already an object

Comment: nope it's a string. i use typeof and it is returning me a string.

Comment: Then `JSON.parse(str)`

Comment: Damn took me so long to figure it out but you solved it for me in less than 10 secs. Thanks @adeneo

Comment: It is not a valid json

Answer (score 0):

You have not valid json, you can add `,` if you creating this by your own

```
[{"id":123, "name": "Sally", "age": 36} // no , not valid
{"id":138, "name": "Nicholas", "age": 48} // no , not valid
{"id":194, "name": "Steven", "age": 25}]

[{"id":123, "name": "Sally", "age": 36}, // <- you need , here
{"id":138, "name": "Nicholas", "age": 48}, // <- you need , here
{"id":194, "name": "Steven", "age": 25}]
```

But If get this string from somewhere, you can add `,` before doing `JSON.parse` and make your string a valid json.

```js
var a = `[{"id":123, "name": "Sally", "age": 36}
{"id":138, "name": "Nicholas", "age": 48}
{"id":194, "name": "Steven", "age": 25}]`

var b = JSON.parse(a.replace(/\n/gim, ','));
console.log (b)
```

Comment: I don't understand how you were able to post an answer after it was closed as a duplicate. In any case, it doesn't matter if he had commas or not. It would seem it was a typo as the OP clearly thanked adeneo for the answer in the comments.